# Start msbuild process in parallel using FOR loop under a batch file

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, msbuild

I want to parallel start msbuild using a for loop. I have below code which builds sequentially where the foor loop starts build in sequence. I want to start build in FOR loop for all the games instantly and wait till all the process finishes.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL

SET CONFIG_DIR=_config
SET /P BUILD_TYPE=<%CONFIG_DIR%\BUILD_TYPE.txt
SET CURRENT_DIR=%cd%
SET TIME_STAMP=%date:~7,2%_%date:~4,2%_%date:~10,4%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%

SET /P MSBUILD=<%CONFIG_DIR%\BUILD_EXECUTABLE.txt

SET GAMES_SLN_DIR=Runtime\core\Games
SET GAMES_PROPS=games.properties

REM Remove log files
del /s /q "%GAMES_SLN_DIR%\MSBuild_*.log"

REM Build Games
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%g IN (%CONFIG_DIR%\%GAMES_PROPS%) DO (
    cd %GAMES_SLN_DIR%
    echo Building Game %%g
    call %MSBUILD% %%g.sln /t:Clean /p:Configuration="%BUILD_TYPE%"
    call %MSBUILD% %%g.sln /p:Configuration="%BUILD_TYPE%" /p:Platform="x64" /l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile="MSBuild_%%g_%BUILD_TYPE%_%TIME_STAMP%.log"
)

cd %CURRENT_DIR%

echo DONE

if "%BUILD_ALL%"=="" (
    pause
)
```

Comment: Use the start command instead of call.

Comment: I tried that, but if I use "start" instead of "call", then it opens up visual studio.

Comment: Unless you show us exactly how you used the `START` command, we can't help you troubleshoot the problem. We also need to see what values all of the variables are expanding to.  Since you have all of them sitting in text files, we can't help you troubleshoot as well.  Use the [edit] option to update your question with that information.